# Choose selected option in HTML select list from SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a select list in an ASP webpage that looks like so:

```
                          <select id="selrAF3" runat="server" onchange="selrouteonchange()" class="select">
                                <option class="selroute" value="V"></option>
                                <option class="selroute" value="I"></option>
                                <option class="selroute" value="Q"></option>
                                <option class="selroute" value="O"></option>
                                <option class="selroute" value="M"></option>
                            </select>
```

I have an SQL query in the codebehind that obtains one of the option values (V, I, Q, O, M), and I want the selected value in the select list to be that letter.  I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. I've only found resources on populating the whole select list from an SQL query, but that's not what I want to do. I merely want the SQL query to select one of the values already there.

Comment: What "type" of ASP.net? MVC? Webforms? Something else? Seeing you have `runat="server"` I'm guessing webforms.

Comment: Correct. Webform.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the `asp:DropdownList` control instead. Generic HTML controls are limited to what you have access to.

```
<asp:DropDownList id="selrAF3"
                OnClientChanged="selrouteonchange()" class="select"
                runat="server">

              <asp:ListItem  Value="V"></asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="I"></asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="Q"></asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="M"></asp:ListItem>
           </asp:DropDownList>
```

Then in your code behind:

```
 selrAF3.SelectedValue = /*Your SQL Value Here*/
```

**UPDATE**

As you have your drop Down in a gridview you'll need to add an [OnRowDatabound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) to your Gridview. Once you've done that, in the code behind you want something similar to:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList ddSelRAF3 = e.Row.FindControl("selrAF3") as DropDownList;
        ddSelRAF3.SelectedValue = /*Your SQL Value Here*/

    }
}
```

Comment: I used your exact code and an error in the codebehind says "The name 'selrAF3' does not exist in the current context". Any idea why?

Comment: Is this in another data container like GridView, repeater etc? If not try adding another DropDownList to the page and test if you can access that in the code behind via it's ID as a debugging excercise.

Comment: Gridiew adds a new degree of difficulty as you no longer have 1 control, you have many each with a unique ID. Does the selected item the same for every row in the Gridview or different for each row?